# Capture cancelled UI with Sheet's container script

Tags: google-apps-script

Can a container script inside of Sheets capture when a user cancels a UI shown with UiApp or HTML Service?

You can do it with `var result = Browser.MsgBox('text'); Logger.log(result);`
If user clicks the X in the top right corner of that pop-up, you get 'cancel' in the result variable.

Trying to replicate the same thing with UiApp. 
`var result = ss.show(app);` doesn't work.

Can we remove the X, if that event isn't available to see?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A UI shown with UiApp does not have a built in 'cancel' control. In fact you just can't cancel a UiApp UI - it just stays there in your browser window until you browse another URL.

In UiApp you can use a PopupPanel that will overlay your UI. This panel does not have built in cancel controls as well.

Short story: You can't have a cancel event handler because ther are no cancel events.

Comment: We can close / cancel a Ui in sheets (see image), so the control is there.